# WPF - ConvertBack для коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

Имеется список всех контрагентов `Contractors`, имеется список партнеров `Partners`, второй список есть подмножество первого, оба свойства доступны в `VM`.

Во `View` есть `ItemsControl` с `CheckBox'ами` в котором содержится список контрагентов:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Contractors}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}">
                ...
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

мне нужно теперь расставить флажки в чекбоксах для всех контрагентов, которые являются партнерами:

```
                <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CheckPartnersConverter}">
                        <Binding Mode="OneWay"/>
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.Partners"
                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </CheckBox.IsChecked>
```

В конвертере реализовал метод `Convert`:

```
class CheckPartnersConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[1] is List<Contractor> partners && values[0] is Contractor c)
            return partners.Contains(c);
        return false;
    }
```

хорошо, это, вроде, работает.

Как теперь реализовать обратное конвертирование и вообще возможно ли его реализовать?

```
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var res = new object[]
        {
            Binding.DoNothing,
            Binding.DoNothing
        };
        return res;
    }
}
```

Если это невозможно, готов отказаться от представления чекбоксами и заменить его, например на `ListBox` с `SelectionMode="Multiple"` и партнеров просто выделять, но там тоже проблемы с `SelectedItems` победить не удается

Comment: Я правильно понял логику, пользователь в списке выделяет контрагентов, далее вы хотите во `ViewModel` получить всех выделенных контрагентов что бы потом сделать их партнерами?

Comment: @sp7, совершенно верно

Comment: Пользователь ставит или снимает галочки. Тут ваш вопрос меня на мысль натолкнул... Чекбокс - это ведь кнопка, можно привязать команду на него...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, вы усложняете себе жизнь.

Смотрите, ваша бизнес-логика хочет отобрать из контрагентов партнёров. Это существенный кусок бизнес-логики, а значит, имеет смысл не пожалеть завести для него отдельный VM-класс:

```
class MaybePartner : NotifyPropertyChangedImpl
{
    public Contractor Contractor { get; }

    bool isPartner;
    public bool IsPartner
    {
        get => isPartner;
        set
        {
            if (Set(ref isPartner, value))
            {
                // тут можно включить контрагента в список или исключить его
            }
        }
    }

    public MaybePartner(Contractor c, bool isInitiallyPartner)
    {
        Contractor = c;
        isPartner = isInitiallyPartner;
    }
}
```

Теперь ваша задача тривиальна: вы при входе в эту часть бизнес логики создаёте список `MaybePartner`'ов, и привязываетесь просто как

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MaybePartners}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Contractor.Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsPartner}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Вроде бы всё.

Comment: Спасибо, была идея создать обертку, но так я ее и не развил, не в то русло мысли уходили, это приходит с опытом, наверное...

Comment: Осталось теперь придумать как оповестить владельца коллекции о том что нужно добавить/удалить контрагента. Предложите, может, ваше решение? Подписаться на INPC? Так это потом ещё отписываться надо, иначе память будет утекать. Может зевести 2 поля делегатного типа, в которые помещать методы для вставки/удаления?

Comment: @Андрей: Ну, например в качестве самого простого варианта можно передавать коллекцию `Partners` прямо в каждый `MaybePartner`. Ну или два делегата, если нужна кастомная логика. Или передавать ссылку на другую VM, у которой есть открытые методы `AddPartner` и `RemovePartner`. А может быть, вообще не нужно ничего делать, а модифицировать список потом, по нажатию OK юзером.

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут на самом деле задачу можно решить несколькими способами, один из них это использовать `EventTrigger`, есть еще вариант с (`attached property` и `behavior`), но на самом деле суть этих решений примерно одна.

`XAML` код:

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox"
             Grid.Row="0"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
             SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItems}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

Далее во `ViewModel` создаем команду:

```
public Command<IList> SelectedItemChangedCommand { get; set; }
```

В качестве параметров `Action'`a данной команды как-раз таки и будут выделенные записи

```
SelectedItemChangedCommand = new Command<IList>(items => 
{
    foreach (User item in items)
    {
    }
});
```

P.S. Для работы с `EventTrigger` и `InvokeCommandAction` у вас должна быть подключена библиотека `System.Windows.Interactivity`.

В `XAML` подключение данного пространства имен выглядит следующим образом:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

---

Для того, что бы привязка к свойству `SelectedItems` работала в двух направлениях, т.е. что бы была возможность устанавливать данное свойство из `VM`, можно воспользоваться механизмом `attached property`. При его использовании `EventTrigger` уже не нужен.

```
public class SelectedItemsAttachedProperty
{
    public static IList GetSelectedItems(ListBox obj)
    {
        return (IList)obj.GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedItems(ListBox obj, IList value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty
        SelectedItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "SelectedItems",
                typeof(IList),
                typeof(SelectedItemsAttachedProperty),
                new PropertyMetadata(null,
                    SelectedItemsChanged));

    private static void SelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lb = d as ListBox;

        if(lb == null)
            return;

        IList coll = e.NewValue as IList;

        if (coll is INotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            (coll as INotifyCollectionChanged)
                .CollectionChanged += (s, collArgs) =>
                {
                    if (collArgs.OldItems != null)
                        foreach (var item in collArgs.OldItems)
                            lb.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
                    if (null != collArgs.NewItems)
                        foreach (var item in collArgs.NewItems)
                            lb.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                };
        }

        if (coll != null)
        {
            if (coll.Count > 0)
            {
                lb.SelectedItems.Clear();
                foreach (var item in coll)
                    lb.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }

            lb.SelectionChanged += (s, lbArgs) =>
            {
                if (null != lbArgs.RemovedItems)
                    foreach (var item in lbArgs.RemovedItems)
                        coll.Remove(item);
                if (null != lbArgs.AddedItems)
                    foreach (var item in lbArgs.AddedItems)
                        coll.Add(item);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

`XAML`

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0"
       wpfApp:SelectedItemsAttachedProperty.SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}"
       DisplayMemberPath="Name"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
       SelectionMode="Multiple" />
```

Следовательно затем во `VM` вы можете добавлять элементы в `SelectedItems`, которое привязано к нашему `AttachedProperty`.

Comment: А как в вашем решении начальные данные отобразить? Ну т.е. у меня `Partners` изначально может быть не пустым

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Answer (score 0):

Переделал пока вот так:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Contractors}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectionMode="Multiple"
         DataContextChanged="OnDataContextChanged"/>
```

Код обработчика события:

```
private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listBox = sender as ListBox;
    if (e.OldValue is Provider oldProv)
        oldProv.Partners = listBox.SelectedItems.Cast<Contractor>().ToList();
    if (e.NewValue is Provider newProv)
    {
        listBox.SelectedItems.Clear();
        foreach (var c in newProv.Partners)
            listBox.SelectedItems.Add(c);
    }
}
```

В принципе всё работает и решение такое меня устраивает. Подсказал бы кто как его адаптировать к варианту представления с чекбоксами.

Comment: Это что, бизнес логика на code-behind при использовании MVVM? Фу-фу-фу

Comment: @AGS17, ничего зазорного не вижу, это чисто представленческая задача - отображение данных пользователю + реакция на действия пользователя и передача их в `VM`. Но я не специалист, конечно.

Comment: @AGS17, предложите, может быть, свое решение?