# Обработка данных в дочернем окне MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно реализовать добавление продуктов в категории через диалоговое окно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал такое окно:

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CategoryTemplate"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildCategories}">
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Title}" 
                  Checked="CheckBox_Checked"
                  Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" />

    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoryTemplate}" />
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class AddToCategoryWindow : Window
{
    public List<CategoryVM> SelectedCategories { get; }
    public AddToCategoryWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SelectedCategories = new List<CategoryVM>();
    }

    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var categoryVm = (sender as CheckBox).DataContext as CategoryVM;
        SelectedCategories.Add(categoryVm);
    }

    private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var categoryVm = (sender as CheckBox).DataContext as CategoryVM;
        SelectedCategories.Remove(categoryVm);
    }
}
```

А дальше вызываю это окно из VM и забираю выбранные категории из свойства `SelectedCategories`:

```
private void AddToCategory()
{
    var addToCategoryDialog = new AddToCategoryWindow() {DataContext = this};
    if (addToCategoryDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        // Тут идет обработка продуктов
    }
}
```

Не уверен, что этот подход правильный.

Подскажите, как нужно делать такие вещи в MVVM?

Comment: Ссылки, которые должны помочь вам сообразить ответ: 1. Сервис создания окон WPF MVVM https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/218063 ; 2. Создание обертки со свойством `IsSelected` (чтобы не подписываться на события `Checked/Unchecked`): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/681274/218063

Comment: Еще как вариант, если ваше дочернее окно не сильно загружено - можно использовать вместо него `Popup` или `ToolTip`, должно получить довольно красиво

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогли эти ответы:

1) [Как показать модальное окно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523553/)

2) [Сервис создания модальных и немодальных окон в контексте паттерна MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525998/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0-mvvm)

3) [OpenFileDialog и MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576471/openfiledialog-%D0%B8-mvvm?noredirect=1&lq=1)

4) [Метод, ожидающий действие пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/449911/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F?noredirect=1&lq=1)